# TSQL PATINDEX / CHARINDEX to find consecutive line breaks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Consider a nvarchar column in SQL Server with the following string in it

```
"Test line



Test line after four line breaks."
```

I can see four line breaks(CRLF) in the aforementioned string if I paste the data in notepad ++ and enable symbols. I was just wondering if the following TSQL statement is correct re finding this string,

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'%', DataField) From Foo
```

Unfortunately this query is not returning me the expected result and the integer return value is always 0. Ideas?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

While the text is showing 4 sets of CRLF (Carriage Return Life Feed) in notepad++, when I output every single character from where I am encountering linebreaks using ASCII function in TSQL, it's giving me

```
CHAR(13)CHAR(13)CHAR(10)CHAR(13)CHAR(13)CHAR(10) (e.g. \r\r\n\r\r\n) if I am not wrong
```

Any explanation re this!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE/EDIT

CRLF is short for Carriage Return/Line Feed. This is ofcourse ancient terminology that is mostly deprecated in the literal meaning of the words.

With "modern" systems there is no carriage to return and even when this command is not given new text starts from the left hand side. Some programs always give a full CRLF when enter is pressed but there are also programs that only send a line feed. And then there are the worst kind, that give full CRLF when ending a line with text but only a line feed when the line being left is empty. This is technically an "optimalization" because hey, why "return the carriage" when it never left the starting position.

Thats all very nice but how do you fix it?

Replace all you char(13) that are not followed by a char(10) with a full set. Look carefully at how to do this because if you get it wrong you might go inserting CRLFs indefinitly on a loop ;)

END EDIT

I've tried exactly what you describe, see code sample below. It should work just as you describe. for some extra testing I even inserted the linebreaks as quoted text, works. Even datatype text which was my first guess of possible misbehaving seems to support this fully. I first ran this on my own system with 2012 but realized your question specified 2008 so I tested it on fiddle for 2008 and got the same result.

Conclusion: the problem is not in selecting patindex on linebreaks ;)

```
create table crlf_test (id int identity(1,1), nstring nvarchar(100), string varchar(100), n_text ntext)

insert crlf_test (nstring, string, n_text) values
('a'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'b','a'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'b','a'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'b'),
('a

b','a

b','a

b')

select * from crlf_test
select patindex('a'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'b', nstring)
    , patindex('a'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'b', string)
    , patindex('a'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'b', n_text)
from crlf_test
select patindex('a

b', nstring)
    , patindex('a

b', string)
    , patindex('a

b', n_text)
from crlf_test
```